# Linux AMT Tool always throws 404 error

Tags: linux, intel, motherboard

I am using the Linux command `amttool` to communicate with another PC on the local network with AMT installed in order to communicate with the machine independently of the disk system to obtain motherboard information. I have successfully been able to get basic power data from the machine via a [Python tool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amt/0.4.0) but does not provide much more detailed information. The Linux `amttool` however shows that it can 'print some machine info' according to the man page.

The information I'm looking to be able to extract would be statistics like CPU usage, disk usage, RAM usage etc. However running this on the command line:

```
AMT_PASSWORD=<amt_password> amttool <amt_host_ip> info
```

always returns this error:

```
### AMT info on machine <amt_host_ip> ###
AMT version:  9.0.30
404 Not Found at /usr/bin/amttool line 242.
```

where the line number where the error supposedly happened changes depending on the command, in this case we are asking for machine information with `info`. Providing any other possible command returns a `404` stating a different line number for the location of the error.

I know this isn't an authentication issue because prior to passing the password correctly to `amttool` I was thrown `401 unauthorized` error messages instead. Also because passing the same credentials to the above linked Python amt tool succeeds.

What could the possible problems be? Could it be a buggy version? Is there a setting that is missing on the host machine side?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting the same thing on my Lenovo TS140, which has AMT 9.1.0.

I think the problem is that AMT 9 removed SOAP support, which `amttool` relies on.  `amttool` is a perl script using SOAP::Lite.  In fact the Python tool you reference has this in its README

> There was once a tool called `amttool` which let you interact with
>   these systems from Linux. This used the SOAP interface to AMT. That
>   was removed in v9 of the firmware, which means it no longer works with
>   modern AMT in the field. -https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amt/0.4.0

Hope that help.